Derivation of variance ratio test
I have been studying the variance ratio test of lo and mackinley (1988) to apply ata  paper.
I found this calculations in this site: https://mingze-gao.com/posts/lomackinlay1988/ 
Maybe, someone here knows how to explain the derivation of the Homoscedasticity and the Heteroscedasticity assumption for the asymptotic variance?

My only advice is to find the original paper by Lo and Mackinlay. Here is the abstract. https://web.mit.edu/Alo/www/Papers/lo-mackinlay-88.html
